# pre compile flags optimisation

Tags: c, precompile

I am wondering how I could optimise (re-write) following code in a better way? 
Thanks

```
#if SOME_THING
    #ifndef OTHER_THING
    return somefun();
    #else
    return otherfunc();
    #endif

#else
    return otherfunc();
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `defined` operator-like thingy (available only as part of preprocessor conditionals) to roll the two conditionals together.

```
#if SOME_THING && !defined(OTHER_THING)
    return somefun();
#else
    return otherfunc();
#endif
```

Comment: The `defined` operator-like thingy doesn't even require parentheses.

Comment: @unwind Huh, learn something new everyday. And thanks for confirming the terminology. ;)